Add ICU library to C++ project in Visual Studio 2022
I need to use ICU library for my project. I have downlowaded it from the website. But I cannot link and use it in my C++ project.
I have tried these steps:

Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties".
Add ICU Include Directory:
Go to "C/C++" -> "General" -> "Additional Include Directories".
Add the directory where the ICU headers are located (usually the include directory in the ICU source code).
Add ICU Library Directory:
Go to "Linker" -> "General" -> "Additional Library Directories".
Add the directory where the ICU static library (.lib) is located (usually the lib directory in the ICU build).
Specify ICU Libraries:
Go to "Linker" -> "Input" -> "Additional Dependencies".
Add the ICU static library names (e.g., icuuc.lib, icuin.lib, etc.). Make sure to include all the necessary ICU libraries your project depends on.

I downloaded icu4c-74_2-Win64-MSVC2019.zip from this link: github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-74-2.
When I followed the instruction, no errors were displayed when I write the program in VS2022.
But when I build, I was announced: unresolved external symbol  referenced in function main. I have read the page you linked but I'm still unable to manage to use it.
How can I use the library? Can you give me an intruction to work with this library. And will the project still work on other computers which do not install ICU library?

What exactly did you download? Where did you extract it? When you followed the steps in your question what happened? Where is the code causing the issue? Did you read the page I linked on your previous question about this?

I downloaded icu4c-74_2-Win64-MSVC2019.zip from this link: https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-74-2. And I extracted it to a folder in F: disk.
When I followed the instruction, no errors were displayed when I write the program in VS2022. But when I build, I was announced: unresolved external symbol  referenced in function main.
I have read the page you linked but I'm still unable to manage to use it.
Thank you so much for your answers.

What are the exact errors? Add your code and the errors to the question.

This is my code:
#include <icu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unicode/utypes.h>
#include <unicode/ustdio.h>
#include <unicode/localpointer.h>
typedef struct UFILE UFILE;
int main() {
const UChar* fileName = u"F:\midterm - project - test - data\test - data.csv";
UFILE* fptr = u_fopen_u(fileName, "r", NULL, NULL);
if (fptr == NULL) {
u_printf("Lỗi: Không mở được file.\n");
return 0;
}
UChar buffer[1024];
while (!u_feof(fptr)) {
u_fgets(buffer, 1024, fptr);
u_printf_u(buffer);
}
u_fclose(fptr);
return 0;
}

Error: LNK2019 unresolved external symbol u_fclose referenced in function main

[edit] your question to add details. Make sure you have added all of the libraries you're using to the additional dependencies in the Visual Studio project.
